# My Mac OS X 10.5 netstat reveals a lot of open UDP connections

Tags: osx-leopard, netstat

here are my netstat results (besides server-less connections):

```
Active Internet connections  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49224     r1.ycpi.vip.sp2..http  ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49223     r1.ycpi.vip.sp2..http  ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49203     lax04s01-in-f189.https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49201     lax04s01-in-f19..https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49198     lax04s01-in-f19..http  ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49196     lax04s01-in-f19..https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49194     lax04s01-in-f19..https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49192     lax04s01-in-f19..https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49183     r1.ycpi.vip.sp2..http  ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0     37  192.168.1.98.49179     l1.login.vip.sp1.https CLOSING  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49175     lax04s01-in-f104.https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0     37  192.168.1.98.49167     l1.login.vip.sp1.https LAST_ACK  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49164     lax04s01-in-f19..https ESTABLISHED  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49174     69.31.112.122.http     TIME_WAIT  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.49173     69.31.113.83.http      TIME_WAIT  
udp4       0      0  *.ipp                  **.*                    
udp4       0      0  192.168.1.98.ntp       **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.49628                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.51997                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.64675                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.61947                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.65152                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.55643                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.51704                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.59757                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.53643                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.65346                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.61960                **.*                    
udp4       0      0  **.*                    **.*                    
udp6       0      0  localhost.ntp          **.*                    
udp4       0      0  practivate.adobe.ntp   **.*                    
udp6       0      0  localhost.ntp          **.*                    
udp6       0      0  *.ntp                  **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.ntp                  **.*                    
udp6       0      0  *.mdns                 **.*                    
udp4       0      0  *.mdns                 **.**                    
udp4       0      0  *.**                    **.**                    
udp4       0      0  *.**                    **.**
```

omitted a few asterisks, basically all the empty spots are asterisks
what is up with all the UDP connections listening on any port?
is that what this means?
the internet activity that should be going in is that i connected via wpa to wifi at a small restaurant visited a few pages, checking mail from a few different accounts, no new mail or downloads where done.
?

Comment: Mine isn't too far off that. Dns/nslookup/google the ones you can (http://www.google.co.uk/search?&client=opera&q=lax04s01-in-f19..https is worrying but inconclusive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to troubleshoot it if you know what process makes those connections, there should be a parameter which you can use to show the processes. In Windows it is `-o`, if not, you could look for a tool that does this...

Comment: cool, i did a 'man netstat' on mac osx in a bash terminal; the command on osx is 'netstat -A' and it showed some more info; i think everything is fine...